# Python ThreadedTCPServer: "Name or service not known"

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ffmpeg, daemon

I was developing a ThreadedTCPServer to communicate with a PHP application also residing in this same machine. This is suppose to receive requests from this PHP app and to convert some videos locally using ffmpeg.

Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import os
import socket
import threading
import logging.config
import SocketServer, time
from queuev2 import QueueServer

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d] %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', filename=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'converter.log'), level=logging.INFO)

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = "{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data)
        videoPool.add(data)
        print "Output! %s" % data
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.info("Initializing...")
    videoPool = QueueServer()
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 6666

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
    # more thread for each request
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)

    # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()

    print("Server loop running in thread: %s" % server_thread.name)

    # "Groundhog day" time
    while True:
        time.sleep(999)
        pass

    #server.shutdown()
```

This works well in my development laptop, but on the server i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 31, in <module>
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the port I'm using (6666), but I've  tried others and it hasn't been working. Would Unix Domain Sockets be of use here? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a port issue.
Unix Domain Sockets nailed it.